# How to add multiple Mandrill API DKIM and SPF on the same domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, mandrill

I have a website in which different suppliers will have their own Mandrill/Mailchimp API to use, and our website will use this API to send emails through their API and using their templates.

While configuring the API mandrill needs to add DKIM and SPF to the domain TXT records.

TXT record for mandrill._domainkey.domainname

So I can't add the same host twice on the domain DNS, how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the same DKIM and SPF are used for the same domain name even if it is different Mandrill accounts.